# Projection conversion issues; Philippines to OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinate-system, philippines

I am working with some roads and bus routes data in Philippines. The bus routes data is in Philippines Zone 4: ESPG 3124 projection. I am trying to match it to roads data to generate stops at intersections. For that I got a roads shapefile from Open Street Maps which was in EPSG 3857 projection.

The two files (roads and routes) don't align and I am guessing this is because of the difference in projection as shown below. Roads are in black and routes in colors with OSM as the basemap.

[image]

I have tried converting the Philippines projection to OSM (right click on the shapefile and "save as" the new projection) and converting  both to WSG84, but without success. Either one of the shapefiles disappear or the new projected seems to have no change.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to load your data into a new QGIS project after converting the projection to WGS84? Then did they still not overlap each other?

Comment: They simply don't match. Happening all the time

Comment: Which Philippines projection, Luzon 1911 or PRS92? Perhaps you've got Luzon data defined as PRS92 (or the other way around). This pdf should shed some light on Philippine specific coordinate systems http://www.asprs.org/a/resources/grids/08-99-phillipines.pdf

Comment: @ahmadhanb Yes I did. I get this error: "Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits"

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Its PRS92.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I tried loading the routes file as a Lazun projection like you suggested and zoomed to layer. Its scale turned out to be: 1:-2,147,483,648. When I did the same for the roads layer (from OSM), its scale was v different at: 1:109,364. In contrast, loading the routes file in the PRS92 projection is at a scale of 1:107,118. This seems more accurate. I am quite certain that the routes file is meant to be in PRS92 projection (I was told this by the shapefile provider) and the trouble is with figuring out what projection can I convert it to get it to match it with OSM data.

Comment: Then perhaps it's not so much a projection problem as an accuracy problem. How much is the difference? It looks like only a few metres; check the metadata statement on both datasets about accuracy and see if you're within the stated accuracy limits, if this is the case there's nothing you can do with CRS to make the data line up... from here you'd need to rubbersheet with FME or ArcGis to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you Michael, it may just be an accuracy issue. Currently I can only see the distances in degrees in this projection and am unable to convert the projection to a meters friendly format (due to the error mentioned earlier) so its hard to guess how much the error is. I will try reclassifying the routes shapefile or perhaps snapping it to the nearest roads.